# How can I access val1 and val2 in int main?

Tags: c++, oop

I have tried using scope resolution with main and get() but it seems like I am not doing anything here right.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {

public:
  float val1, val2;
  void get() { cout << "Enter two values..." << endl, cin >> val1 >> val2; }

  friend float mean(base ob);
};

float mean(base ob) { return float(ob.val1 + ob.val2) / 2; }

int main() {
  base obj;
  obj.get();
  cout << "Mean of " << val1 << " and " << val2 << " is: " << mean(obj);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that you should be able to access them from `main`? Aren't you the person that declared them private and had to make `mean` a friend?

Comment: @molbdnilo I moved it to public also but it still did not work

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: `val1` and `val2` are non-static members of `base`. You’ll need a `base` instance whose members to access.

Comment: please do not fix the code in your question according to solutions in comments or answers. The broken code belongs into the question, fixed code is for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make `val1` and `val2` accessible from outside the class:

```c
...
class base {
    public:
        float val1, val2;
    public:
...
```

Then you need to specify that you want to access `val1` and `val2` that belong to object `obj`:

```c
cout<<"Mean of "<<obj.val1<<" and "<<obj.val2<<" is: "<<mean(obj);
```

You can also make `mean()` a bit better:

```c
float mean(const base& ob) {
    return float(ob.val1+ob.val2)/2;
}
```

If you don't want to make `val` and `val2` public then you can make public methods that will return their values:

```c
class base {
  float val1, val2;
public:
  auto get_val1() const { return val1; }
  auto get_val2() const { return val2; }
```

Comment: Why is that definition of `mean` "better"?

Comment: Redefined `mean` is (in theory) faster because it will not copy object, but only pass a reference to it. Copying objects, especially if they are big, can be expensive. Passing a reference is cheap. Also, by marking reference `const` you enable compiler to optimize code better because you are letting it know you will not be changing the object.

Comment: @Mestkon: From C++20, you could use `std::midpoint` for the mean of two values. Which takes care of overflow etc.